# Infopath 2013 does not point to a valid location path of a field or group

Tags: infopath2010

Ok, really no clue here, I have this SharePoint list that contains everyone's department, which I set up to receive information from. I have also set up a txtField call txtUserName, it gets the user name of the user accessing the page. Then I created this formula that would allow me to get the users department from the list using the username as a lookup:

Department[translate(ClaimsAccountName, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") = translate(txtUserName, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")]

The problem is when I go to verify formula, it kicks this back out at me:

"xdXDocument:GetDOM("UPS")/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW/d:Department/my:txtUserName" does not point to a valid location path of a field or group.

Given that I got everything out of the insert field or group function, I just have no idea how this is happening?

Anything would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out, the xpath was wrong when I tried to insert the field, I am guessing this is a bug that needs to be reported to MSFT, but whatever. To fix it, I simply right clicked on the data field, and choose to copy XPath, then I went to insert the function again, and I choose to edit the XPath on that, which gave me the bad XPath, which I replaced with the good one.